# Is it possible to change Color on a per line basis in NSTextField?

Tags: swift, macos

I have a Swift Mac OS X project with a NSTextField where I display multiple lines of text. I can change the color of all the text in the text field

```
    searchResult_field.stringValue = result
    searchResult_field.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
```

But I'd like to be able have some lines the default color and others a different color.

Comment: What do you mean by "line"? Do you mean per-punctuated line, where line breaks occur? Or do you mean per-physically drawn line on screen, where one sentence might run across multiple horizontal lines and that one sentence should be drawn in multiple colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSAttributedString` to color each range of the string in a different color.